# iOS creating a reusable view woes

Tags: ios, view, storyboard, reusability

I am trying to create a custom view, with a nib and attendant .h/.m files, and then create multiple instances of that view via IB, and use them as subviews of another view.

1. I created the .h/.m files
2. I created the xib.
3. For the xib, I specify the class name in IB.
4. Add some labels to the xib (the values for which will be programmatically changed)
5. I drag a simple view in storyboard into my container view.
6. I set the class of the dragged view to the class i specified for the xib.

I do steps 5 and 6 multiple times, once for each view I want.  Eventually I would connect these views to IBOutlets on the parent view class.

Obviously I am doing something wrong because I am not seeing my labels in the custom view.  I suspect I need to associate the nib with the view directly, much like you do with collection/table view, but I haven't found where to do this.

What is the correct way to do this?  I suppose I could add views programmatically, but then how do I handle the layout for various devices (e.g. iphone 4 vs 5)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I outline below appears to work

1)  Create the xib and .h/.m files for your custom view.
1a)  Assuming you need IBOutlets to view elements over which you want control, give the **File's Owner** the class name defined in your .h file in the identity inspector.

2)  In .h file define a property

`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;`

2a)  define outlets for all the subviews in your xib, to which you want programmatic access.

3) In the .m file synthesize the property and do

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"awake from nib");
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourNibName" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
}
```

4) Drag empty views from the palette into their container in the storyboard.  Change the class 
of these views to the class name defined in your .h file.

When you run your app you should see the contents of the xib in your subviews.

5)  You can now define outlets to your custom subview instances in the .h file of the container view, and connect them as usual in the storyboard.

Comment: This works great! One minor piece of instruction left out, is that your superview in your nib, should be referenced to that 'contentView' property in it's outlets

Comment: As a note, I like to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([CustomView class]) owner:self options:nil];` Prevents any mistakes and provides some structure and convention.

Comment: Thank you to @1dayitwillmake for the crucial piece of instruction. Without this it does not work.

Comment: @AdamWaite for me your string does not work. At runtime it is unable to locate a nib based on the "CustomView" class, which is the class set to the owner of the xib if I understand correctly

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a view in a xib and use it in a storyboard. If you already have it created in a xib file, you can copy and paste it into your storyboard. If you want it to be the root view of a controller, delete the view that you get with the controller, and paste in the one from the xib. You can then change the class of those views to your custom class.

I'm not sure what you mean by "children of another view" -- views don't have a parent-child relationship, it's a view-subview relationship. Also, you don't usually (ever?) drag a view into a container view. The container view contains a view controller which you get automatically when you add a container view to another view. That controller is a child of the controller whose view has the container view in it. If you want your custom view to appear where that container view is, then you would add that view to the child controller's view (or replace that view with yours).

Comment: yes, I meant subviews.  Basically I want 7 subviews contained within another view, each of those subviews being an instance of the same class.  I'd like to be able to layout the internal components (subviews) of these 7 subviews in a xib.  EDIT -- I am aware I can't get see the actual xib in the storyboard -- I am content to just see the white outline of the view i dragged from the object selector (bottom right of IB), as long as when the app runs, the actual view contains what the xib contains

Comment: @hvgotcodes, as I said you can't do it that way. You need to copy and paste the view from your xib into the storyboard -- then you will see all the internal components.

Comment: what I outline out below worked for me and does what I describe.

Comment: This isn't true. I use custom nibs and storyboards all the time.

Comment: You might want to read what Apple has to say on the subject: [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)